# How to prevent user registrations based on IP address using devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rubygems

I have a rails-4.0.0 application. I'm using devise gem for authentication. I have to restrict users from registering multiple times based on their ip for a single or 'N' number of days.

I have tried using **last_signed_ip** as,

```
Registration.where("created_at >= ? AND last_sign_in_ip = ?", Date.yesterday, request.remote_ip).count >= 2
```

Is this the best way, or do I have any other method to restrict the user registrations.

Comment: you can validate model   validates :last_sign_in_ip, uniqueness: true,   check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

Comment: Thank you, but doing so will permanently prevent user registrations from that particular IP.  I need to restrict users from registering multiple times based on their IP per day.

Comment: validates :last_sign_in_ip, uniqueness: { scope: :day,
    message: "should happen once per day" }, can use scope with validation

Comment: This seems good, but this will allow only one registration per day from that IP.

Comment: create custom validations. Refer this [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations).